# GPS. Always same point

Tags: android, gps

I wrote a small app to log my GPS position.
It works well but on the phones I get strange results.

If I put a phone on the bench and start logging after maybe 20 given points GPS starts to give me new points all with the same Long/lat/alt. When I move maybe 2-3 metres away situation is same. 20 points with different coords. After that all with the same.

It's not a problem with:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, listener);
```

As you see there is no minTime and minDistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I Found my answer.
Some gps chipsets like SirfStar IV have something called "Static navigation" which disable getting location updates when you are not moving.